# Owl carousel i cannot add 2 caroousel in 2 rows

Tags: html, owl-carousel

I want o add two owl-carousel in one page HTML 
example  row 1 .  =  owl-carousel1
         row 2 .  =  owl-carosoul2

```
                <div class="item">
                <!-- Item Image -->
                <div class="item-image"><img src="assets/img/image1.jpg" class="img-medium" alt="Ceo"></div>
                <!-- Item Image End -->

                <!-- Item Description -->
                <div class="item-desc">
                    <a class="link" href="#">
                        <div class="desc-content">
                            <span class="yellow">CEO</span>
                            <span class="title">Name Lastname</span>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                    <ul class="social-icons social-white nav-default clearfix">
                        <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-google"></i></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <!-- Item Description End -->
            </div>
        <!-- Item List End -->
    </div>
```

when i add example a new  it doesnt appear in the 2nd column ?
anybody help my is HTML

Comment: Can't help without knowing the javascript that you are using... this is a javascript question.

Answer (score 0):

here is a little bit code of  owl-team.js

```
    $.fn.owlCarousel = function (options) {
    return this.each(function () {
        if ($(this).data("owl-init") === true) {
            return false;
        }
        $(this).data("owl-init", true);
        var carousel = Object.create(Carousel);
        carousel.init(options, this);
        $.data(this, "owlCarousel", carousel);
    });
};
```